# When creating an ECS task with terraform it is missing required attributes for pulling image from ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, containers, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

When I try to create an AWS ECS task with terraform [ecs_task_definition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition) the task is created successfully but it is missing some required attributes (com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth,        ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull
) which prevents from the container to pull the image from ECR.

When I create the task using AWS CLI with the same parameters (including the same roles for 'execution role' and 'task role') it do add all required attributes and the container successfully pull the image from ECR.

The container definition json is:

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "container_main_env-test1",
            "image": "586289480321.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/XXXX-saas:latest",
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memory": 5000,
            "essential": true,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/XXXX-test1",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The task definition is:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "XXXX_task_definition" {
  family        = var.name
  task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.XXXX_ecs_task_role.arn
  execution_role_arn    = "arn:aws:iam::586289480321:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
  container_definitions = var.container_definition_content
}
```

The json above is passed as parameter to this definition on 'var.container_definition_content'

Is there a known bug about it or some tweak that I am missing?

Thanks,
Ronen

Comment: What exactly is the error message. Also what exactly is `var.container_definition_content`?

Comment: The error is: ```Status reason CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get https://586289480321.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws/v2/: dial tcp: lookup 586289480321.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws on 10.0.0.2:53: no such host```

Comment: The ```var.container_definition_content``` includes the container definition json I put above

Comment: That error doesn't sound like a task definition problem, it sounds like a networking (DNS lookup) problem. The VPC subnet you are deploying this ECS task to likely doesn't have a NAT Gateway route, or an ECR privatelink.

Comment: I also thought the same but I went over all configuration and they are OK. Moreover, when I deploy the task with the same configuration but instead of using terraform I do it with aws cli everything works